# Joins using Map Reduce programming

Tags: csv, join, mapreduce, bigdata

I have two `csv` files. One has `(user_id, gameName,score)` and other has `(user_id, age)`. How do I perform a join using map reduce programming so that I can calculate average age of players for each game. I have no idea how to proceed with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using two **MapReduce** jobs. First, joining the both datasets. Second, calculating the average age of players per game.

Lets call dataset `(user_id ,gameName,score)` as **`GameSet`** and `(user_id ,age)` as **`AgeSet`**.

First, **JoinMapreduce** job will have two mapper definition separately for each dataset. These mapper tasks will output the `user_id as key` and `record as value` with a identifier appending as prefix to the record. Lets say this prefix is **"game"** for first dataset and **"age"** for second dataset. This is required to identify the record in `Reducer`. The `Reducer` will receive two values in list for each key (assuming no duplicates in data). The identifier will help us identify the record and we will create a `new record`, which will have all the information about the user like `gameName`, `score`, and `age`. The output of the reducer will have `gameName as key` and `record as value`. (if you want to optimize then you can just emit the age of the user.)

Second, the output from the first MapReduce job is `GameName as Key` and `Record as Value`. This will be input for the next **AvgAgePerGame MapReduce** job. It will have the **identity mapper**, which will emit the input as mapper output. Now at the reducer, you will receive `GameName as key` and `list of records` (list of ages) as value. You can sum the age of players and divide them by the number of player in the reduce method. Output the key (GameName) and avg. age as value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @YoungHobbit is correct. The solution to your problem can be achieved by a combination of `ReduceSide joins` which uses `MutlipleInputFormat` and `Chaining jobs`.

I have implemented the entire MapReduce code for this problem which can be found at my github repo [here](https://github.com/Prabhu-Moorthy/WorkArea).

We need to use 2 Mappers namely GameMapper and AgeMapper for the 2 files that we need to join. This can be achieved by `MultipleInputFormat`.

Next we use a reducer to join the data from both the mappers and write the output to HDFS. This can be achieved by `Reduce Side Joins`

Next we write another MR job which uses the output of the previous MR job as Input. This mapper emits the game name as key and the age as value for each record.

Finally a reducer is written where the logic takes place to find out the average age of users for each game.The output is then written to HDFS.

Both the MR jobs are called from a single Driver class in my implementation. This is achieved by `Chaining Jobs`.

For more information regarding my implementation of this problem please look at the Readme file in the github repo [here](https://github.com/Prabhu-Moorthy/WorkArea).

Comment: it will be great if you could provide me with an explanation as well .

Comment: Updated my answer with additional explanation.

Comment: Thanks a ton! both of you